# Any "fromfile_prefix_chars" equivalent for Python-Click

Tags: python, argparse, python-click

Is there any equivalent in Click (https://click.palletsprojects.com/) for the [`fromfile_prefix_chars`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#fromfile-prefix-chars) option that is available in the argparse library?

I sometimes have lot of arguments to hand over to a Click based application and - especially when using file paths - may reach some Windows limits. Therefore, when using argparse, the solution was to use the `fromfile_prefix_chars` option. However, we will move to Click now.

Is there any equivalent available or is it possible to replicate this functionality in Click?

Many thanks for your help.

Best regards,
gpxricky

Comment: There doesn't appear to be, implementing this yourself seems trivial though

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. You can use [default_map to override defaults](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.1.x/commands/#overriding-defaults)

You could do it in various ways:

## Pass file with python dictionary

You could parse a python dictionary with `ast.literal_eval`:

```py
import ast
import click
import os


@click.group()
@click.pass_context
def main(ctx):
    config = os.getenv('CLICK_CONFIG_FILE', './click_config')
    if os.path.exists(config):
        with open(config) as f:
            ctx.default_map = ast.literal_eval(f.read())


@main.command()
@click.option("--param", default=2)
def test(param):
    print(param)


if __name__ == '__main__':
     main()
```

Let's assume we have two config files:

```py
# click_config
{
    'test': {'param': 3}
}
```

```py
# config_click
{
    'test': {'param': 4}
}
```

Now, here is what happens when you call your command:

```bash
# Highest precedence, overrides any config file
$ python main.py test --param 1
1
# No config file exists. Takes the default, defined in the command
$ python main.py test 
2
# Default config file exists, overrides default to 3
$ python main.py test 
3
# Custom config file provided, overrides default to 4
$ CLICK_CONFIG_FILE=./config_click python main.py test 
4
# Again. The command line has the highest precedence:
$ CLICK_CONFIG_FILE=./config_click python main.py test --param 1
1
```

## Pass yaml config file

You could follow [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73669230/14033765) to do the same thing with yaml.

## Pass ini file

[Here](https://jwodder.github.io/kbits/posts/click-config/) you can find an article explaining how to adopt ini files.

## Use an extension (the config format is again ini)

Check [this](https://github.com/click-contrib/click-configfile) out.